# have no experience

Tags: negation, quantifiers

a. Each of these drinks have no calories.

b. Each of these workers have no experience.

Are the sentences grammatically correct?

Are they natural?

Answer (score 1):

These sentences are neither grammatically correct nor idiomatic. Generally, when we want to say the same thing about a number of items. we use **all**:

> All of these drinks [contain] no calories.
> All of of these workers have no experience.

If we want to say that something is unique about every one of a number of things, we use **each**

> Each of these drinks **has** its own flavour.
> Each of these workers **has** unique skills.

Note that, when we use **each**, we are talking about the individuals from the group as single entities, so we use a singular verb **has** rather than a plural verb **have**.